# BigQuery issue: shwoing : Incompatible table partitioning specification

Tags: google-bigquery

I have created one bgquery table with partition in date field and clustered in id field. I have used terraform to create the table. But when I try to insert data in the table , I am getting error as :

> com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryException: Incompatible table
>   partitioning specification. Expects partitioning specification
>   interval(type:day,field:forecast_start) clustering(customer_id), but
>   input partitioning specification is
>   interval(type:day,field:forecast_start)
>
> Caused by:
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400
>   Bad Request 17:00:01  { 17:00:01    "code" : 400, 17:00:01    "errors"
>   : [ { 17:00:01      "domain" : "global", 17:00:01      "message" :
>   "Incompatible table partitioning specification. Expects partitioning
>   specification interval(type:day,field:forecast_start)
>   clustering(customer_id), but input partitioning specification is
>   interval(type:day,field:forecast_start)", 17:00:01      "reason" :
>   "invalid" 17:00:01    } ], 17:00:01    "message" : "Incompatible table
>   partitioning specification. Expects partitioning specification
>   interval(type:day,field:forecast_start) clustering(customer_id), but
>   input partitioning specification is
>   interval(type:day,field:forecast_start)", 17:00:01    "status" :
>   "INVALID_ARGUMENT"

Any suggestion?

Comment: This doesn't look like an error at insertion time. More context from the error log or code?

Comment: I am doing BQ to BQ load using BQ api.Here is the log :17:00:01  com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryException: Incompatible table partitioning specification. Expects partitioning specification interval(type:day,field:forecast_start) clustering(customer_id), but input partitioning specification is interval(type:day,field:forecast_start)
17:00:01   at com.google.cloud.bigquery.spi.v2.HttpBigQueryRpc.translate(HttpBigQueryRpc.java:99)
17:00:01   at com.google.cloud.bigquery.spi.v2.HttpBigQueryRpc.getQueryResults(HttpBigQueryRpc.java:401)
17:00:01   at

Comment: Add more context please. Log? code?

Comment: Interestingly if I copy data using bq command from one table to other it is working fine. But if I try using api , I am getting the error

Comment: How are you using the API, context please - code?

Comment: Looks like you specified the partitioning field but not the clustering field in your query job. You can either specify both, or none. If you specify it, BQ will use it to create the destination table if it doesn't exist; if the destination table exists, BQ will check it matches the destination table.

Comment: [Here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-clustered-tables#sample_table_used_in_the_examples) you can find an example on how to use both filters at the same time, as explained before. @HuaZhang your reply seems to be the correct one. Can you please post it as an answer so the community can find it more easily? Thanks.

Comment: @HuaZhang , yes it is correct. I didn't specified the cluster in my query job but I have specified the partitioning. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you specified the partitioning field but not the clustering field in your query job. You can either specify both, or none. If you specify it, BQ will use it to create the destination table if it doesn't exist; if the destination table exists, BQ will check it matches the destination table.

Posted on behalf of @HuaZhang

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be one another scenario also causing this error,
Alterring where class of source query (with our source column changes) eliminates this error.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34768976)